# java.net.unknownhostexception unable to resolve host no address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android, asp.net, web-services

I uploaded a webservice in somee.com (a free asp.net hosting server). when i browse it, it is running perfect. But, when i consumed it in android app, it is not working. i put all the below url addresses.

(1)String SOAP_ACTION = "tempuri.org/getLatLong";

(2)String OPERATION_NAME = "getLatLong";

(3)String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "tempuri.org";

(4)String SOAP_ADDRESS = "fypandroid.somee.com/webService.asmx";

And i am receiving the error "java.net.unknownhostexception unable to resolve host no address associated with hostname."

Someone please help me. Thanks.

MyWebService: fypandroid.somee.com/webService.asmx
PS: I put http:// in all links, becuase of less reputation i couldnot enter the links.

Comment: Problem solved. Mobile was apparently not connected to the wifi. :P

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the web service ??

I think you are testing it in an Emulator. Since the service is in a real server, I prefer using a real device. Also, using emulator is OK. But some emulator shows weird behavior with real web services. Try using a different emulator, preferably a newly created one.

Comment: I am testing it on my android cellphone. (virtual device)

Comment: My bad, i am testing it on REAL DEVICE.